# How can I share a network interface with docker without setns error?

Tags: docker

I want to fire up 2 docker containers on the same interface, so I tried the following from the docker docs:

```
First container:
bash-4.1$ docker run -ti --name=target ubuntu /bin/bash
root@45edefd42404:/# 

Second container:
bash-4.1$  docker run -ti --rm --net=container:target ubuntu /bin/bash
setup networking failed to setns current network namespace: invalid argumentFATA[0002] Error response from daemon: Cannot start container ba28e4f14f4b3c2d7b94aa4b0cca8f5b70e6b354842818fe77b31885acc77461: setup networking failed to setns current network namespace: invalid argument
```

I've googled for failures related to `setns` and can't find anything relevant.  Is there anyplace else I can look to debug this?

My docker daemon log contains this related to the failure (full log https://gist.github.com/paulweb515/990a1a9edeef1e73b752);

```
time="2015-04-23T09:17:59-04:00" level="error" msg="Warning: error unmounting device ba28e4f14f4b3c2d7b94aa4b0cca8f5b70e6b354842818fe77b31885acc77461: UnmountDevice: device not-mounted id ba28e4f14f4b3c2d7b94aa4b0cca8f5b70e6b354842818fe77b31885acc77461\n"
time="2015-04-23T09:17:59-04:00" level="info" msg="+job log(die, ba28e4f14f4b3c2d7b94aa4b0cca8f5b70e6b354842818fe77b31885acc77461, ubuntu:14.04)"
time="2015-04-23T09:17:59-04:00" level="info" msg="-job log(die, ba28e4f14f4b3c2d7b94aa4b0cca8f5b70e6b354842818fe77b31885acc77461, ubuntu:14.04) = OK (0)"
Cannot start container ba28e4f14f4b3c2d7b94aa4b0cca8f5b70e6b354842818fe77b31885acc77461: setup networking failed to setns current network namespace: invalid argument
```